# How do I create pages in a web api project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to display a default status page for my web api project (where instead some IIS message is displayed when I start the project). However it seems like I cannot create views in web api (there is no support for ActionResult).

In addition to a status page I will also use this information to create an api documentation page.

How can I achieve displaying html pages in this situation ?

Answer (score 2):

If your default status page is static html, you don't have to use MVC. Just tell WebApi in your `Startup.cs` that you want to support static resources:

```
app.UseFileServer();
```

For creating an API documentation, maybe you could write that file on startup dynamically?

Comment: How would i then display the static file ?

Comment: Just call it index.html and it would be displayed automatically (depends on your IIS configuration).

Comment: @MichaelS left out one small step. You will want to create a folder called "wwwroot" and put the "index.html" file in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create regular controllers and views in a webAPI project the same as any MVC project. Just create a normal controller that does not inherit from ApiController. In your startup.cs make sure to configure at least a default route.

```
 configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "someName",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Right click and select Add, then you should see controller at the top. Select one of the mvc controllers.

[image]

Comment: But then i will need to add mvc references to use this right ?

Comment: Yes you would need to add the proper references if they are not already there. When you create a new webAPI project there are already regular controllers and a views folder. Once you've created your view go to the properties page of the project and set your view to the start up page if you are wanting to see it when your project starts up.